# Youtube embeded code is validation using Regex in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to validate an embedded code is valid or not. if anyone has an idea that how to check with regex. below code only check URL. but I want to check all string. The below code is not working.

```
var P = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/

P.test('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_sWcXaic-bw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
```

P variable only checks URL.

It's working

```
P.test('https://www.youtube.com/embed/_sWcXaic-bw');
```

but only check URL not the full tag is not working

Answer (score 0):

I am trying this below code and it's working, but I don't know is valid or not. Please post if you have any valid solution for this.

```
var P = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/

var content = '<p>'+'<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_sWcXaic-bw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+'</p>'

if($(content).find("iframe").length > 0){
   var srccheck =  $(content).find("iframe").attr("src")
    if(P.test(srccheck)){
        console.log("valid")
    }else{
        console.log("not valid")
    }
}else{
    console.log("not valid")
}
```